# How to make prediction if trend/lag values are used as predictors?

Tags: r, time-series, prediction, trend

I have a 3-year hourly sales dataset(9-6 pm, Monday to Saturday only) and would like to make predictions either for a day or a week ahead with linear regression. The dataset has excluded all the national holidays since the store is not open. This time-series data presents strong intra-day and intra-week seasonalities and shows a high peak around national holidays. So I extracted the following variables for feature engineering:

(1) time-related features: timestamp("2021-02-01 09:00:00"), hour, weekday, month, year
(2) one-week-lag variable
(3) trend variable by decomposing "trend" from historical data and add as a new predictor

```
decomp_ts <- decompose(ts)
data$trend <- decomp_ts$trend
```

(4) holiday dummy variables indicating the day before holidays

The model works fine, but I encounter two questions when deploying the model with the real-time data.

(1) I wanted to use predict() with a future dataset of a week ahead as input for the "newdata" argument. But my mind is twisted as I am not sure how to do with the trend variable. Should I run an additional prediction on trend for the next week and add this info back to the future dataset to predict the sales?

(2) How would you suggest generating the one-week lag data considering the missing values caused by holidays? In my case, a store may open only two days in Christmas week, then the one-week-lag variable for the next week will contain missing values for the days when the store is not open.

I look forward to any suggestions.

Comment: The trend is a function of the last estimated level, as per the formula [here](https://otexts.com/fpp2/holt.html). Therefore, I believe that you only need the training dataset to obtain it.

Comment: Question 2, would you agree that you might reduce the impact of the difference of working days in each week if you use week number as an input. I think that the model would learn more easily that in the Christmas week it achieves a certain amount, regardless of the number of working days.

Comment: @PauloSchauGuerra thank you for the feedback! I obtained the forecasted trend for the future week with auto.arima() function and add the forecasted trend back to the future dataset to feed in predict() function. Is my approach correct?

Comment: @PauloSchauGuerra Would you mind explain a bit more about using the week number as an input? Do you mean to add the week number, for example, week 52 of the year, as one of the variables in the model?

Comment: The auto.arima() should be able to predict data points in the future by simply understanding the patterns of change over time up to that point. Now, I believe that an ARIMA model is only good for time series, where you will have datetime as index and a value to be predicted. You will need a different model to compound the results of the arima() with the other features.